# How to refresh the page and make data not available after refreshing that page in APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to refresh my page and after refreshing the data is still available where after refreshing I don't want data to be present on that page. How can I achieve this one?

NOTE: I have just created a blank page and not the page with form.
Can someone help me as I am new to APEX?

On click of the refresh button, the data shouldn't present.  Kindly let me know how can I achieve it?

[image: ORACLE APEX]

Answer (score 0):

In apex your data is cached for performance reasons. If you refresh it just will pick up the data from the cache again. You can change this behaviour by clearing the cache for that page. That option is available from all the places where you link to another page (button, branch, link, list entries, etc).

Comment: Did it work ? If so can you please mark the question as answered.